# Get values of radio buttons in a while loop php

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I am having following code  in my form..how do I get the value of all radio button values . I am using for each loop but still I get only the last value

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultselect,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){  ?>

<input type="radio" name="site<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" id="su" value="1"/>

<input type="radio" name="site<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" id="sf" value="2" />

<input type="radio" name="site<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" id="so" value="3" class="selected" />>

<?php  $counter++; }
```

This is the for each loop where I am expecting the values

```
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val){

      if(substr($key, 0, 4) == 'site'){

        print_r($val);
      }
    }
```

Comment: `name="site[<?php echo $counter; ?>]"` or even better `name="site[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]"` assuming your id column is named `id`. You do not need `substr`.

Comment: you want to select single radio  or multiple radio selection at a time? or from three we are able to select only single radio?

Comment: Each row has these 3 buttons . SIngle radio are selected for each row . I want values of each row but it returns only 1 row value . Please help me to figure out where I am going wrong

Comment: Thank you  Quasimodo's clone I used  name="site<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" and looped for the submit to get ids and value

Answer (score 0):

Radio button is by default array. you don`t have to mention []:

Every row has different radio buttons with counter like site1,site2

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultselect,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{?>
   <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="radio" name="site<?php echo $counter;?>"  value="1"/>
    <input type="radio" name="site<?php echo $counter;?>"  value="2" />
    <input type="radio" name="site<?php echo $counter;?>"  value="3"/>
    <td>
   </tr>
   <?php
   $counter++; 
}?>
```

When you select radio from every `'<tr>'` then the value of the selected radio will be send if there is `'<tr>'` with not selected radio button then it will not be post.

for loop:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
   echo "KEY:".$key."=>Value:".$value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I figured it out used ids for the names of the radio